# Submenu adding wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress page which has the following menu layout.

1. Primary Menu

   2. Sub menu
2. Primary

   4. List item

I would like to add another Submenu to the Submenu (Submenuception)

1. Primary

   2. Sub menu

      3. Sub Sub menu

My current theme doesn't support it and how can I add it via code.
Can someone help me pointing at the right direction. Thanks!

Added the code of the themes nav-menu-template:

```
<?php
/**
 * Navigation Menu template functions
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Nav_Menus
 * @since 3.0.0
 */

/**
 * Create HTML list of nav menu items.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @uses Walker
 */
class Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker {
    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     */
    public $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu\">\n";
    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
    }

    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     * @param int    $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        /**
         * Filter the CSS class(es) applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array  $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param object $item    The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filter the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param object $item    The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args    An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $class_names .'>';

        $atts = array();
        $atts['title']  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target'] = ! empty( $item->target )     ? $item->target     : '';
        $atts['rel']    = ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? $item->xfn        : '';
        $atts['href']   = ! empty( $item->url )        ? $item->url        : '';

        /**
         * Filter the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title  Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel    The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href   The href attribute.
         * }
         * @param object $item  The current menu item.
         * @param array  $args  An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         * @param int    $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filter a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param object $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int    $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param array  $args        An array of {@see wp_nav_menu()} arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param object $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int    $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments. @see wp_nav_menu()
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }

} // Walker_Nav_Menu

/**
 * Displays a navigation menu.
 *
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param array $args {
 *     Optional. Array of nav menu arguments.
 *
 *     @type string        $menu            Desired menu. Accepts (matching in order) id, slug, name. Default empty.
 *     @type string        $menu_class      CSS class to use for the ul element which forms the menu. Default 'menu'.
 *     @type string        $menu_id         The ID that is applied to the ul element which forms the menu.
 *                                          Default is the menu slug, incremented.
 *     @type string        $container       Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with. Default 'div'.
 *     @type string        $container_class Class that is applied to the container. Default 'menu-{menu slug}-container'.
 *     @type string        $container_id    The ID that is applied to the container. Default empty.
 *     @type callback|bool $fallback_cb     If the menu doesn't exists, a callback function will fire.
 *                                          Default is 'wp_page_menu'. Set to false for no fallback.
 *     @type string        $before          Text before the link text. Default empty.
 *     @type string        $after           Text after the link text. Default empty.
 *     @type string        $link_before     Text before the link. Default empty.
 *     @type string        $link_after      Text after the link. Default empty.
 *     @type bool          $echo            Whether to echo the menu or return it. Default true.
 *     @type int           $depth           How many levels of the hierarchy are to be included. 0 means all. Default 0.
 *     @type object        $walker          Instance of a custom walker class. Default empty.
 *     @type string        $theme_location  Theme location to be used. Must be registered with register_nav_menu()
 *                                          in order to be selectable by the user.
 *     @type string        $items_wrap      How the list items should be wrapped. Default is a ul with an id and class.
 *                                          Uses printf() format with numbered placeholders.
 * }
 * @return mixed Menu output if $echo is false, false if there are no items or no menu was found.
 */
function wp_nav_menu( $args = array() ) {
    static $menu_id_slugs = array();

    $defaults = array( 'menu' => '', 'container' => 'div', 'container_class' => '', 'container_id' => '', 'menu_class' => 'menu', 'menu_id' => '',
    'echo' => true, 'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu', 'before' => '', 'after' => '', 'link_before' => '', 'link_after' => '', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth' => 0, 'walker' => '', 'theme_location' => '' );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    /**
     * Filter the arguments used to display a navigation menu.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see wp_nav_menu()
     *
     * @param array $args Array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $args = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args', $args );
    $args = (object) $args;

    /**
     * Filter whether to short-circuit the wp_nav_menu() output.
     *
     * Returning a non-null value to the filter will short-circuit
     * wp_nav_menu(), echoing that value if $args->echo is true,
     * returning that value otherwise.
     *
     * @since 3.9.0
     *
     * @see wp_nav_menu()
     *
     * @param string|null $output Nav menu output to short-circuit with. Default null.
     * @param object      $args   An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $nav_menu = apply_filters( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', null, $args );

    if ( null !== $nav_menu ) {
        if ( $args->echo ) {
            echo $nav_menu;
            return;
        }

        return $nav_menu;
    }

    // Get the nav menu based on the requested menu
    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $args->menu );

    // Get the nav menu based on the theme_location
    if ( ! $menu && $args->theme_location && ( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() ) && isset( $locations[ $args->theme_location ] ) )
        $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations[ $args->theme_location ] );

    // get the first menu that has items if we still can't find a menu
    if ( ! $menu && !$args->theme_location ) {
        $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
        foreach ( $menus as $menu_maybe ) {
            if ( $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_maybe->term_id, array( 'update_post_term_cache' => false ) ) ) {
                $menu = $menu_maybe;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // If the menu exists, get its items.
    if ( $menu && ! is_wp_error($menu) && !isset($menu_items) )
        $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id, array( 'update_post_term_cache' => false ) );

    /*
     * If no menu was found:
     *  - Fall back (if one was specified), or bail.
     *
     * If no menu items were found:
     *  - Fall back, but only if no theme location was specified.
     *  - Otherwise, bail.
     */
    if ( ( !$menu || is_wp_error($menu) || ( isset($menu_items) && empty($menu_items) && !$args->theme_location ) )
        && $args->fallback_cb && is_callable( $args->fallback_cb ) )
            return call_user_func( $args->fallback_cb, (array) $args );

    if ( ! $menu || is_wp_error( $menu ) )
        return false;

    $nav_menu = $items = '';

    $show_container = false;
    if ( $args->container ) {
        /**
         * Filter the list of HTML tags that are valid for use as menu containers.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param array $tags The acceptable HTML tags for use as menu containers.
         *                    Default is array containing 'div' and 'nav'.
         */
        $allowed_tags = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_container_allowedtags', array( 'div', 'nav' ) );
        if ( in_array( $args->container, $allowed_tags ) ) {
            $show_container = true;
            $class = $args->container_class ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $args->container_class ) . '"' : ' class="menu-'. $menu->slug .'-container"';
            $id = $args->container_id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $args->container_id ) . '"' : '';
            $nav_menu .= '<'. $args->container . $id . $class . '>';
        }
    }

    // Set up the $menu_item variables
    _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( $menu_items );

    $sorted_menu_items = $menu_items_with_children = array();
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        $sorted_menu_items[ $menu_item->menu_order ] = $menu_item;
        if ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent )
            $menu_items_with_children[ $menu_item->menu_item_parent ] = true;
    }

    // Add the menu-item-has-children class where applicable
    if ( $menu_items_with_children ) {
        foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as &$menu_item ) {
            if ( isset( $menu_items_with_children[ $menu_item->ID ] ) )
                $menu_item->classes[] = 'menu-item-has-children';
        }
    }

    unset( $menu_items, $menu_item );

    /**
     * Filter the sorted list of menu item objects before generating the menu's HTML.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param array  $sorted_menu_items The menu items, sorted by each menu item's menu order.
     * @param object $args              An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $sorted_menu_items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', $sorted_menu_items, $args );

    $items .= walk_nav_menu_tree( $sorted_menu_items, $args->depth, $args );
    unset($sorted_menu_items);

    // Attributes
    if ( ! empty( $args->menu_id ) ) {
        $wrap_id = $args->menu_id;
    } else {
        $wrap_id = 'menu-' . $menu->slug;
        while ( in_array( $wrap_id, $menu_id_slugs ) ) {
            if ( preg_match( '#-(\d+)$#', $wrap_id, $matches ) )
                $wrap_id = preg_replace('#-(\d+)$#', '-' . ++$matches[1], $wrap_id );
            else
                $wrap_id = $wrap_id . '-1';
        }
    }
    $menu_id_slugs[] = $wrap_id;

    $wrap_class = $args->menu_class ? $args->menu_class : '';

    /**
     * Filter the HTML list content for navigation menus.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see wp_nav_menu()
     *
     * @param string $items The HTML list content for the menu items.
     * @param object $args  An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $items = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_items', $items, $args );
    /**
     * Filter the HTML list content for a specific navigation menu.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see wp_nav_menu()
     *
     * @param string $items The HTML list content for the menu items.
     * @param object $args  An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $items = apply_filters( "wp_nav_menu_{$menu->slug}_items", $items, $args );

    // Don't print any markup if there are no items at this point.
    if ( empty( $items ) )
        return false;

    $nav_menu .= sprintf( $args->items_wrap, esc_attr( $wrap_id ), esc_attr( $wrap_class ), $items );
    unset( $items );

    if ( $show_container )
        $nav_menu .= '</' . $args->container . '>';

    /**
     * Filter the HTML content for navigation menus.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see wp_nav_menu()
     *
     * @param string $nav_menu The HTML content for the navigation menu.
     * @param object $args     An object containing wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    $nav_menu = apply_filters( 'wp_nav_menu', $nav_menu, $args );

    if ( $args->echo )
        echo $nav_menu;
    else
        return $nav_menu;
}

/**
 * Add the class property classes for the current context, if applicable.
 *
 * @access private
 * @since 3.0.0
 *
 * @param array $menu_items The current menu item objects to which to add the class property information.
 */
function _wp_menu_item_classes_by_context( &$menu_items ) {
    global $wp_query, $wp_rewrite;

    $queried_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $queried_object_id = (int) $wp_query->queried_object_id;

    $active_object = '';
    $active_ancestor_item_ids = array();
    $active_parent_item_ids = array();
    $active_parent_object_ids = array();
    $possible_taxonomy_ancestors = array();
    $possible_object_parents = array();
    $home_page_id = (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

    if ( $wp_query->is_singular && ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) && ! is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) get_object_taxonomies( $queried_object->post_type ) as $taxonomy ) {
            if ( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy ) ) {
                $term_hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy( $taxonomy );
                $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $queried_object_id, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
                if ( is_array( $terms ) ) {
                    $possible_object_parents = array_merge( $possible_object_parents, $terms );
                    $term_to_ancestor = array();
                    foreach ( (array) $term_hierarchy as $anc => $descs ) {
                        foreach ( (array) $descs as $desc )
                            $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] = $anc;
                    }

                    foreach ( $terms as $desc ) {
                        do {
                            $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $taxonomy ][] = $desc;
                            if ( isset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] ) ) {
                                $_desc = $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ];
                                unset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] );
                                $desc = $_desc;
                            } else {
                                $desc = 0;
                            }
                        } while ( ! empty( $desc ) );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } elseif ( ! empty( $queried_object->taxonomy ) && is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $queried_object->taxonomy ) ) {
        $term_hierarchy = _get_term_hierarchy( $queried_object->taxonomy );
        $term_to_ancestor = array();
        foreach ( (array) $term_hierarchy as $anc => $descs ) {
            foreach ( (array) $descs as $desc )
                $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] = $anc;
        }
        $desc = $queried_object->term_id;
        do {
            $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $queried_object->taxonomy ][] = $desc;
            if ( isset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] ) ) {
                $_desc = $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ];
                unset( $term_to_ancestor[ $desc ] );
                $desc = $_desc;
            } else {
                $desc = 0;
            }
        } while ( ! empty( $desc ) );
    }

    $possible_object_parents = array_filter( $possible_object_parents );

    $front_page_url = home_url();

    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {

        $menu_items[$key]->current = false;

        $classes = (array) $menu_item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item';
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-type-' . $menu_item->type;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-object-' . $menu_item->object;

        // if the menu item corresponds to a taxonomy term for the currently-queried non-hierarchical post object
        if ( $wp_query->is_singular && 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type && in_array( $menu_item->object_id, $possible_object_parents ) ) {
            $active_parent_object_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->object_id;
            $active_parent_item_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->db_id;
            $active_object = $queried_object->post_type;

        // if the menu item corresponds to the currently-queried post or taxonomy object
        } elseif (
            $menu_item->object_id == $queried_object_id &&
            (
                ( ! empty( $home_page_id ) && 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && $wp_query->is_home && $home_page_id == $menu_item->object_id ) ||
                ( 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && $wp_query->is_singular ) ||
                ( 'taxonomy' == $menu_item->type && ( $wp_query->is_category || $wp_query->is_tag || $wp_query->is_tax ) && $queried_object->taxonomy == $menu_item->object )
            )
        ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
            $menu_items[$key]->current = true;
            $_anc_id = (int) $menu_item->db_id;

            while(
                ( $_anc_id = get_post_meta( $_anc_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true ) ) &&
                ! in_array( $_anc_id, $active_ancestor_item_ids )
            ) {
                $active_ancestor_item_ids[] = $_anc_id;
            }

            if ( 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && 'page' == $menu_item->object ) {
                // Back compat classes for pages to match wp_page_menu()
                $classes[] = 'page_item';
                $classes[] = 'page-item-' . $menu_item->object_id;
                $classes[] = 'current_page_item';
            }
            $active_parent_item_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            $active_parent_object_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->post_parent;
            $active_object = $menu_item->object;

        // if the menu item corresponds to the currently-requested URL
        } elseif ( 'custom' == $menu_item->object ) {
            $_root_relative_current = untrailingslashit( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
            $current_url = set_url_scheme( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_root_relative_current );
            $raw_item_url = strpos( $menu_item->url, '#' ) ? substr( $menu_item->url, 0, strpos( $menu_item->url, '#' ) ) : $menu_item->url;
            $item_url = untrailingslashit( $raw_item_url );
            $_indexless_current = untrailingslashit( preg_replace( '/' . preg_quote( $wp_rewrite->index, '/' ) . '$/', '', $current_url ) );

            if ( $raw_item_url && in_array( $item_url, array( $current_url, $_indexless_current, $_root_relative_current ) ) ) {
                $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
                $menu_items[$key]->current = true;
                $_anc_id = (int) $menu_item->db_id;

                while(
                    ( $_anc_id = get_post_meta( $_anc_id, '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', true ) ) &&
                    ! in_array( $_anc_id, $active_ancestor_item_ids )
                ) {
                    $active_ancestor_item_ids[] = $_anc_id;
                }

                if ( in_array( home_url(), array( untrailingslashit( $current_url ), untrailingslashit( $_indexless_current ) ) ) ) {
                    // Back compat for home link to match wp_page_menu()
                    $classes[] = 'current_page_item';
                }
                $active_parent_item_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
                $active_parent_object_ids[] = (int) $menu_item->post_parent;
                $active_object = $menu_item->object;

            // give front page item current-menu-item class when extra query arguments involved
            } elseif ( $item_url == $front_page_url && is_front_page() ) {
                $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';
            }

            if ( untrailingslashit($item_url) == home_url() )
                $classes[] = 'menu-item-home';
        }

        // back-compat with wp_page_menu: add "current_page_parent" to static home page link for any non-page query
        if ( ! empty( $home_page_id ) && 'post_type' == $menu_item->type && empty( $wp_query->is_page ) && $home_page_id == $menu_item->object_id )
            $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';

        $menu_items[$key]->classes = array_unique( $classes );
    }
    $active_ancestor_item_ids = array_filter( array_unique( $active_ancestor_item_ids ) );
    $active_parent_item_ids = array_filter( array_unique( $active_parent_item_ids ) );
    $active_parent_object_ids = array_filter( array_unique( $active_parent_object_ids ) );

    // set parent's class
    foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $parent_item ) {
        $classes = (array) $parent_item->classes;
        $menu_items[$key]->current_item_ancestor = false;
        $menu_items[$key]->current_item_parent = false;

        if (
            isset( $parent_item->type ) &&
            (
                // ancestral post object
                (
                    'post_type' == $parent_item->type &&
                    ! empty( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
                    is_post_type_hierarchical( $queried_object->post_type ) &&
                    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $queried_object->ancestors ) &&
                    $parent_item->object != $queried_object->ID
                ) ||

                // ancestral term
                (
                    'taxonomy' == $parent_item->type &&
                    isset( $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $parent_item->object ] ) &&
                    in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $possible_taxonomy_ancestors[ $parent_item->object ] ) &&
                    (
                        ! isset( $queried_object->term_id ) ||
                        $parent_item->object_id != $queried_object->term_id
                    )
                )
            )
        ) {
            $classes[] = empty( $queried_object->taxonomy ) ? 'current-' . $queried_object->post_type . '-ancestor' : 'current-' . $queried_object->taxonomy . '-ancestor';
        }

        if ( in_array(  intval( $parent_item->db_id ), $active_ancestor_item_ids ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-ancestor';
            $menu_items[$key]->current_item_ancestor = true;
        }
        if ( in_array( $parent_item->db_id, $active_parent_item_ids ) ) {
            $classes[] = 'current-menu-parent';
            $menu_items[$key]->current_item_parent = true;
        }
        if ( in_array( $parent_item->object_id, $active_parent_object_ids ) )
            $classes[] = 'current-' . $active_object . '-parent';

        if ( 'post_type' == $parent_item->type && 'page' == $parent_item->object ) {
            // Back compat classes for pages to match wp_page_menu()
            if ( in_array('current-menu-parent', $classes) )
                $classes[] = 'current_page_parent';
            if ( in_array('current-menu-ancestor', $classes) )
                $classes[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
        }

        $menu_items[$key]->classes = array_unique( $classes );
    }
}

/**
 * Retrieve the HTML list content for nav menu items.
 *
 * @uses Walker_Nav_Menu to create HTML list content.
 * @since 3.0.0
 * @see Walker::walk() for parameters and return description.
 */
function walk_nav_menu_tree( $items, $depth, $r ) {
    $walker = ( empty($r->walker) ) ? new Walker_Nav_Menu : $r->walker;
    $args = array( $items, $depth, $r );

    return call_user_func_array( array($walker, 'walk'), $args );
}

/**
 * Prevents a menu item ID from being used more than once.
 *
 * @since 3.0.1
 * @access private
 */
function _nav_menu_item_id_use_once( $id, $item ) {
    static $_used_ids = array();
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $_used_ids ) )
        return '';
    $_used_ids[] = $item->ID;
    return $id;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_id', '_nav_menu_item_id_use_once', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: What is your current theme?

Comment: Have you tried adding sub sub menu? By default it should support it. The different thing is if the theme developers failed to create sub sub menus. In that case you need to add your css to fix this.

Comment: I think it doesn't support it because I've played with the Apparence->Menu but when I put sub sub menu it doesn't work.
Can you point me to the css I need to fix?

Comment: @dingo_d Can you point me to someway achieve this... ??

Comment: These things are usually done with the walker function. Since I don't know what the walker function of this theme is, I can't be of much help.

When you add the sub sub menu in your menu, and hover on the main menu, when you inspect it, is the new unsorted list inside the css at least? Because if it is all you need is a bit of css to fix this. Give some code as an example so that we can work with it.

Comment: @dingo_d I have added the code of the nav-menu-template where the walker class is located. Would be very helpful if you could take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't add this in comments, but try adding a sub sub menu in your wordpress, and in style.css, or wherever you are adding the css try putting this:

```
.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0 15px;
    background: url("images/submenu-top-bg.jpg") top left repeat-x #F3F3F3;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul > li{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
    background: none;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul li a{
    padding: 8px 0px 12px 0!important;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul li:first-child a{
    padding: 14px 0px 10px 0!important;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul li a:hover{
    display:list-item;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:13px;
    line-height:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #fff;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li ul li a span{
    font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
}
```

And see if the second level menu is working.

**EDIT**

The code has been changed to fix the issue.

**EDIT 2**

Since your jquery is messing stuff up, you can add this:

```
.main-menu li ul.sub-menu li:hover ul{
    display:block!important;
}

.main-menu li ul.sub-menu:before{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:100%;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
}
```

And in your master.js file on line 58 change the code to this:

```
function jsddm_open() {
    jsddm_canceltimer();
    ddmenuitem = jQuery(this).find('> ul').slideDown('fast');
}
```

This will make it so that your sub menu shows on hover.

It's an ugly solution, but it's something. You could probably fiddle around the js file and tweak it so that it works better.

Comment: No it just breaks the formatting and duplicates all the links!

Comment: Well forgot to add pages to submenu. I did it but doesn't show anything.

Comment: Guess you'll have to fiddle with the walker function :\

Comment: Hey I added some depth to the header.php and now it is showing the submenu but not right formated. The most wierd thing is that it adds a margin-top=-16px?

Comment: Tried to remove the css you gave me but it is now showing the submenu as static over my menu and not when I hover.

Comment: It's hard to go at it blind. If you can add web page I could inspect and see the issue.

Comment: ofc forgot. vomtullnerbach.at  
see the fotogaleri part and you will see the problem.
and thanks for helping :D

Comment: Ok, so first of all, remove the code from the top of the style.css (before the body), and put the above code (I updated it) on line 1972 of your css file. This should work now (I had to put the !important to get it to work as it should). This fixed the styling, but the javascript that controls the menu has targeted only `ul` and didn't specify any depth, so when you hover on menu all the submenus will show. This is just poor coding on their part

Comment: thanks for the help. Wouldn't it be possible to add like css hover element to the first submenu so the sub-sub-menu shows only when hovered.
I noticed that it shows without hovering! :(

Comment: Sorry, it works like you posted but when I try to hover above my sub-sub-menu it goes away :( So it shows fine but cant click...

Comment: Sorry put this: `.main-menu li ul.sub-menu:hover li ul{display:block!important;}` instead of hovering on list item. Should work now.

Comment: No it actually displays only the static second one without showing the first if I hover. But yes it doesn't go away.

Comment: Ok, so I checked your site and it works as it should. When you hover on 'Fotogalerie' a first dropdown shows, then you hover on 'A-Wurf Fotogalerie', and then next to it you get the second submenu. Like it should work...

Comment: Yes but actually when I hover over A-WURF it should show A-wurf not the B-Wurf. Thats the problem.

Comment: When I do li:hover it work exactly as expected. When I hover over A it shows A , when over B shows B but when I try to hover over  sub-sub-menu it disappears.

Comment: Ok, put hover on li, and add this: 
`.main-menu li ul.sub-menu:before{
 content:"";
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:100%;
 width:20px;
 height:100%;
}`

Comment: Thanks you really helped me a lot! kudos :D

Comment: Well it's a patch, and you'll need to be careful if you want responsive to work, but you'll get it. I'm surprised that the official support didn't solve this. Glad I could help :)